# Oracle BI TIMESTAMP in hh:mm:ss format

Tags: sql, oracle, business-intelligence

I have the following code:

```
TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_SECOND, CAST(("Agent Performance Facts"."ACD After Call Work Outbound Time (Seconds)" + "Agent Performance Facts"."Inbound Talk Time (Seconds)" + "Agent Performance Facts"."Inbound Hold Time (Seconds)")  AS INTEGER), TIMESTAMP '1999-01-01 00:00:00')
```

How can I get an output format **hh:mm:ss** ?

Comment: use to_char with the proper format mask.

Comment: Where to I place the to_char ?

Answer (score 1):

You can present a `TIMESTAMP` in **hh:mm:ss** format using the `to_char` function.

For example, I've just run the following:

```
select to_char(systimestamp, 'HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

... and it returned:

```
22:30:43
```

Lots of examples to be found and the following gives a pretty good summary:

http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-to_char.html